# When JSON is send over network how are numbers represented (as binary or text)?

Tags: json, firebase, serialization, firebase-realtime-database, encoding

This might be a trivial question... Or might not be. When I serialize an object to JSON how are numbers represented?

Specifically, I need to know how efficiently they are encoded to binary. There are 2 ways:

1. Transform number to its decimal string representation and then encode that string to binary.
2. Or encode the number directly to binary.

Which is the case?

That is a big difference: Let's say serialized object contains number `12345678`. Encoded first way it will take 8 B to transfer, encoded second way only 4 B. When it comes to lots of big numbers (my case) than in the first case I would better use base64 as pre-process for serialization.

I can imagine that this might be dependent on serializer (though I really hope it is not). In that case, I am using Firebase Realtime database SDK.

Comment: As text. JSON is a string.

Comment: If you are especially concerned about how much space it takes up use Gzip to compress your JSON in transit. Browsers will automatically uncompress it on download.

Comment: @bhspencer Cannot do. This transfer is managed by Firebase (using their SDK on my end and their server on their end)...

Comment: is the bandwidth actually a practical issue? If not then stop worrying about it. In my experience the flexibility and ubiquitous adoption of JSON for all languages greatly outweighs the bandwidth increase.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a **textual** notation. So the number `12345678` is sent as those eight characters, 1, 2, 3, etc. Depending on your text encoding, that's probably eight bytes (e.g., UTF-8 or Windows-1252; but if you were using UTF-16, for instance, it would be 16 bytes).

There have been various "binary JSON" proposals over the years, but I don't think any of them really caught on outside of specific applications (for instance, [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) in MongoDB).

Comment: This is what I feared... You have quite a bit of reputation here so I take it for granted but it is still super ineffective.

Comment: @Rasto - Sorry, not quite sure what you mean. :-) (And FWIW, largely ignore rep. Trust is good, but also be sure to verify any answers you get here, whether from a ~700k user or a ~700 user. :-) )